# how to build eastl library

Tags: c++, linux, eastl

Recently I am trying to build eastl library in linux 3.10 x86_64 but failed .

https://github.com/electronicarts/EASTL

do has "Compiling sources"  webpage here :

https://github.com/electronicarts/EASTL/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

follow the instructions and get libEASTL.a , ar -t libEASTL.a get :

```
allocator_eastl.cpp.o
assert.cpp.o
fixed_pool.cpp.o
hashtable.cpp.o
intrusive_list.cpp.o
numeric_limits.cpp.o
red_black_tree.cpp.o
string.cpp.o
thread_support.cpp.o
```

Then a tiny test source :

```
#include <EASTL/vector.h>
#include <EASTL/fixed_vector.h>
int main()
{
    eastl::fixed_vector<int,10,true> v ;
    int iarr[10]  ;
    for(int idx=0;idx<10;idx++){
        iarr[idx] = idx + 1 ;
        v.push_back( iarr[idx] ) ;
    }
}
```

compiled it by :

g++ --std=c++11 -O2 test1.cpp -I/home/mars/tools/EASTL-master/include -I/home/mars/tools/EASTL-master/test/packages/EABase/include/Common /home/mars/tools/EASTL-master/thelib/libEASTL.a -o test1.exe

will get the link error :

undefined reference to `operator new[](unsigned long, char const*, int, unsigned int, char const*, int)'

The eastl library should have a easy way to build and include header files ,
I just miss it , any advice are great appreciated .

Edit  :

After I add this new function , link error is gone !!!

```
void* operator new[](size_t size, const char* pName, 
int flags, unsigned debugFlags, const char* file, int line)
{
    ;
}
```

so the only question left is :  I need to  code this new function right !!!!
to do that ,  any document can give me a clue ?!

Edit2  :

according to this website information :

https://wuyingren.github.io/howto/2016/02/11/Using-EASTL-in-your-projects/

```
void* operator new[](size_t size, const char* pName, int flags, unsigned     debugFlags, const char* file, int line) 
{
    return malloc(size);
}  

void* operator new[](size_t size, size_t alignment, size_t alignmentOffset, const char* pName, int flags, unsigned debugFlags, const char* file, int line) 
{
    return malloc(size);
}
```

then the work is done .

Comment: Try #include <new>

Comment: @Tony ,  #include <new> still has "undefined reference" problem ,

Answer (score 4):

But recommended at original site this >> https://github.com/electronicarts/EASTL/blob/master/doc/CMake/EASTL_Project_Integration.md#setting-up-your-code

```
void* operator new[](size_t size, const char* name, int flags, unsigned debugFlags, const char* file, int line)
{
    return new uint8_t[size];
}
```